# What do the dialogue in the "visual novel" monsters mean and what do they allude to?

Tags: neptunia-rebirth-1

In Hyperdimension Neptunia Rebirth 1, there are monsters that resembles typical visual novel dialogues. They look like these:

[image: Tokimeki Sister]
[image: Violent Good Girl]
[image: Blushing Hot Guy]
[image]

What does the text box dialogue mean when translated to English and which visual novels do they refer to?

Comment: The first character looks like it's supposed to be Shiori Fujisaki from Tokimeki Memorial. It's not really a visual novel though, at least not by the Japanese definition. No idea what the text says.

Comment: Here's someone's translations though it's from a different game in the series: http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/667143-hyperdimension-neptunia-victory/65878281

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since no one has offered a better answer yet, I'll turn my comments into one.

First a translation of the dialogue. My understanding of Japanese is very poor, so I'll just quote [ToInt32's translation posted on GameFAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/667143-hyperdimension-neptunia-victory/65878281):

> **Tokimeki Sister**: A childhood friend's sister says "I love you [brother]. Teehee.
>   Let's do our best again today to build our relationship"
>
> **Violent Good Girl**: Younger sister says "My brother is the nicest in the world!"
>
> **Blushing Hot Guy**: Student President says "Come here; don't be afraid"
>
> **Valentine's Day**: Girl says "Let's compare!! If you win I'll give you some chocolate!"

Notably he's unsure of the translation of the last one. There might be some word play going on there.

As for the games referenced by these monsters I've only been able to figure out one of them. The name "Tokimeki Sister" is a pretty obvious reference to [Tokimeki Memorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokimeki_Memorial), and the girl pictured looks very much like [Shiori Fujisaki](http://tokimemo.wikia.com/wiki/Shiori_Fujisaki) the most popular and well known character from that game and the franchise it spawned. The green background of the text box also appears to be taken from this game, as this [screen shot I found on GameFAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/turbocd/916139-tokimeki-memorial/images/screen-7) shows:

[image: Tokimeki Memorial screen shot showing Shiori Fujisaki and a green text box]

The background of the scene is also what looks to be a typical Japanese high school, the same setting of Tokimeki Memorial. By the way, the item "Palpitation" dropped by this monster is a translation of "Tokimeki". In this context the word is a reference to the palpitations (throbbing, loud beating) of the heart felt when falling in love.

As for the other monsters I strongly suspect they're not actually references to any specific game. Instead I think it's more likely they're references to common types of characters and/or Internet memes.

It's apparently lost in the translation to English, but a [Japanese Wiki for this game](http://wikiwiki.jp/neptune-re1/?%A5%D1%A5%ED%A5%C7%A5%A3%B2%F2%C0%E2#u20289f6) apparently explains that the "Violent Good Girl" monster in original Japanese version was a reference to an obscure(?) Japanese meme, one that is ultimately an indirect reference to the [1985 American film Commando](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commando_(1985_film)). In the original version this monster's name is スネグアヨイコ (Suneguayoiko) which when you reverse the order of the Japanese characters becomes コイヨアグネス or こいよアグネス (Come on, Agnes). [According a Japanese site I found](http://netyougo.com/dj/7230.html) the name Agnes in this phrase refers to [Agnes Chan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agnes_Chan), a pop singer and UNICEF Goodwill Ambassador for Japan, who [campaigned against child pornography](http://www.sankakucomplex.com/2009/03/08/unicefs-agnes-chan-lolicon-otaku-must-reform/) (Warning: possibly NSFW link). This phrase is derived from a catch phrase taken from the movie Commando, こいよベネット (Come on, Bennett), which is was apparently [popular meme fodder on Japanese sites like 2Channel](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/commando#popular-catchphrases).

The other two monsters I guess are references to common archetypes or scenes. Either that or they're references to something very obscure. The "Blushing Hot Guy" monster is called テライケメン (Teraikemen) in the original version, and this is apparently the name of some sort of handsome male archetype in Japan. The scene depicted by the "Valentine's Day" monster, where a girl is giving chocolate to the player on Valentine's Day, is one that could occur in all sorts of games. It's a tradition in Japan for girls to give chocolate to their boyfriends on this day. On the other hand, the headband (a [hachimaki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hachimaki) I guess) reading バレンタイン (Valentine) is unusual. Given the competition implied by ToInt32's translation, this might be reference to something more specific like a cooking battle mini-game or an idol training game.

Finally to help out anyone who wants to do their own translations I've included my transcription of all the Japanese text in these monster's text boxes. You can also use it to  see how laughably bad [Google Translate](https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&hl=en&ie=UTF8&prev=_t&rurl=translate.google.com&sl=ja&tl=en&u=https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/207629/what-do-the-dialogue-in-the-visual-novel-monsters-mean-and-what-do-they-allude/207802&usg=ALkJrhhRko16R6vzAQhd1gAKo1pyfUwv5A#207802) is at translating Japanese to English.

> **幼馴染の妹**「お兄ちゃん大好きよ。うっふん。
>   今日も頑張って幼馴染っちゃおうね♪」
>
> 実妹
>   お兄ちゃんは世界で一番優しいお兄ちゃん
>   なんだよなっ☆
>
> 生徒会長
>   恐がらないでこっちへおいでよ…
>
> 女の子
>   「私と突き合っください！
>   勝ったらチョコをあげます！」

Comment: Could you also add in a transcription for the text on Valentine's Day headband, if possible? Great answer by the way.

Comment: @Frosteeze It's ブレンタイン burentain or Valentine. According to ToInt32 the chocolate box has "battle!!" on it but the text box obscures it in your screenshot. You might be able to see it by adjusting the camera.

Comment: The Valentine's Day text is a bit of a pun. 突き合う is not a real verb (literally, "stab together") but a linguistically open interpretation could read a meaning like "do battle". The joke is that 突き (stab) has the same pronunciation as 付き (attach), which would have formed the real verb 付き合う (to go out with).